# Confusion in understanding a weird definition

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

An $m×n$ matrix $A$ is said to be a row-reduced echelon matrix (or a row echelon matrix) if

1. $A$ is row reduced ,
2. there is an integer $r$ ($0\leq r\leq m$) such that the first $r$ rows of $A$ are non-zero rows and the remaining rows if there are any are all zero rows and
3. if the leading element of the $ith$ non-zero row occurs in the $k_ith$ column of $A$ , then, $k_1<k_2\cdots <k_r$.

I do get the 1st and 2nd prequisite but I really dont get what's meant by the third condition . By row-reduced , the thing intended goes as follows:

> An $m×n$ matrix $A$ is said to be a row-reduced if the first non-zero element in each non-zero row is $1$ (called the leading $1$) and in each column containing the leading $1$ of some row , the leading $1$ is the only non-zero element.

The examples given as row-reduced echelon matrix are :

$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, $ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

But I dont understand what's meant by the third condition . If I am not wrong $k_i$ is just a column name . How are equality or inequality associated with names ? I don'tunderstand the meaning of this absurd inequality:$k_1<k_2\cdots <k_r$...

Comment: In the second of your example matrices, $k_1=2$, $k_2=3$, and $k_3=1$, so condition 3 is violated.  If you moved row 3 up to the top, then you'd have reduced row-echelon form. The point of condition 3 is that the rows should be in the "right" order.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you!Can you please elaborate upon what you mean by "right" order? Although, I had a feeling that there might be a typo in condition 3...So what would be the correct condition in place of it ?...

Comment: The "right order" means that the higher rows have their leading $1$'s further to the left. More formally, that says $k_1<k_2<\dots<k_r$.

Comment: The thing you are missing is that the columns are ordered from left to right. The column "name" is the position in the ordering.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Ok! So are they trying to imply that if the leading 1 in the ith row occurs in the $k_ith $ column then $k_1<k_2<...<k_i<...<k_r$?i.e the inequality order must be maintained , right? But still I think the 2nd example is wrong as pointed out by Andreas Blass...

Comment: To be more specific if we use the term "leading column" as the column in a row where the leading number occurs then the leading column number of row 1, is less than leading column number of row 2, and so on whereby, the column numbers are numbered from 1 from left to right and the rows are numbered in the vertical direction from 1 from top to bottom in an increasing manner ...

Comment: Yes the second example is not in row echelon form.